# What is n' the abreviation of

Tags: abbreviations

Can someone explain to me what `n'` is the abbreviation of. I have found someone using it like `born n' bred`. To me that would be stating a missing letter to shorten it down. But wouldn't it mean `nd` rather than the `and` I think they are trying to mean.

I want to know what `n'` is the abbreviation of.

I have never seen `n'` before and searching through the dictionary did not come back with any results. So I put my question to you. I know what `'n` is the abbreviation of. But, as I said, I have never seen `n'`

Comment: How is this a duplicate? That question asked is there any other examples. I want to know what the `n'` is the abbreviation of.

Comment: @RegDwigнt. First of all I did look in the dictionary. It was not there. As you can see from the answer below it was in the urban dictionary so is not actually a real word. Second I know what `Born 'n bred` means. But since this politcians website said `Born n' bred` I wanted to check to see if it had another meaning that I was not aware out. Your comment is completly pointless and just flat out rude

Comment: It is in the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/n_1). Nonstandard spelling of ’n’ as in _Born 'n' bred_

Comment: If you ask what the **meaning of …n'… is**, it's no wonder people are going to say it means "and". I love to see the politician's face tonight when he receives a comment about a missing apostrophe, as if he (or she) doesn't have better things to worry about.

Comment: The link provided by RegDwight was perfect. The Wiktionary entry contains the "spelling" of n' and says: **Nonstandard spelling of ’n’.** So RegDwight's answer hidden in the link was helpful, and, accurate.

Comment: `n'` is a fairly common abbreviation of `and`.  Using two quote marks is too busy and "clinical" in appearance.

Comment: It is hard to google for a single letter abbreviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***['n or 'n'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/n) (ən)***:

> - (conj.) 
>     ***and:***
>
>   - *Look 'n listen.*

(The Free Dictionary)

***[nd](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nd)*** is not a commonly accepted expression, The Urban Dictionary says;

> - Slang word for and. One of the many reasons I cannot successfully communicate with other teenagers through the internet, since they do not write in clear English.
>
>   - *nd he was like so cute*

Comment: This does not answer my question. It just says it is a conjunction. But does ntot answer my question

Comment: Sorry , are you not asking for what ***'n*** means?

Comment: Not what `'n` means but what `n'` means. As I have seen it as `n'` rather than `'n` As I would guess that `'n` means `an` but what would `n'` mean? If there is a difference

Comment: I've  never seen ***n'***, can you please provide a link where we can see its usage? may be just a misprint of  ***'n.*** as you can see from the link above it may be also usaed as  ***'n'***.

Comment: I was thinking it might of just been a mistype or something but wanted to make sure. And since my search came up blank I asked it on here. I would give the link to the website however it is a UK MP Candidate's website and I do not know if they will be happy about it.

Comment: I guess that it is very likely that it is an ***and***.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am not asking the meaning of an "effin" apostrophe. I know what it is. I am asking what `n'` is the abbreviation of. Since I cannot find it in the dictionary, and it is on a politicians website. Please read all the posts before writting a comment

Comment: @Josh61 It did come to me that it could mean that. However before I am going to tell the guy about his website I wanted to make sure it didn't have a meaning I have never seen/heard of before.

Comment: @Sam  A UK MP's website is, presumably, public and available for viewing, or do you have to pay a fee to see it? Is it members only?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is free. However I do not want to bring it to public attention (I know that not a lot of people will see it but still). Especially on the day of the general election. You are free to try and find it. However I will not give any information about it.

Comment: _Born n' bred_ is a wrongly punctuated version of [_Born 'n' bred_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/n_1). This is not correct English: "Peterborough has only ever had Tory or Labour MPs and the last time we had an MP who was actually born n' bred in the city was way back in 1929!"

Comment: Could still be "spelled" since spelling and as 'n' is still spelling, no?

Comment: Josh do you think this is a "good" question? was it your answer that helped Sam, or the comments that ran between you and him which helped? Which was more useful? After all you said ["Sorry , are you not asking for what **'n** means?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244847/what-is-the-meaning-of-n#comment529800_244849) EDIT. Why? Because comments helped the user, not the answer. This question is OFF TOPIC, and you yourself voted to close it.

Comment: Yes..I voted to close, but I wanted to help to clarify the issue anyway. Is there something wrong with it?  Don't understand your point!

Comment: Well he did technically help. His first answer showed that in the dictionary there is only `'n` and `'n'`. That helped confirm that I am not just useless at searching through a dictionary and couldn't see it myself. The comments did help me edit my question so it was more clear to what the answer should be. Which he did answer by saying that it is only in the Urban Dictionary

Comment: I know he helped, he always does. But as someone with nearly 50k rep, he also knows that users are discouraged from answering similar questions. Again, I repeat, the question is on hold because Josh and a mod voted to close it. I would have voted to close it too, but Josh and a mod beat me to it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I did my job close-voting. Helping with a better understanding  of issues (obvious to our eyes) is nothing wrong or against the site policy, unless you want anyone to feel unwelcome.